# Converting Oracle's Number toBytes and then to Value + Exponent

Tags: c++, oracle, numbers, exponent, occi

I've been looking all around the net for how to convert an Oracle number to something i can use however i've been totally unable to find anybody who has managed to come up with a complete algorithm (particularly with negative exponents).

Some information has been posted on https://gotodba.com/2015/03/24/how-are-numbers-saved-in-oracle/ however this is incomplete as it fails to describe negative exponent solutions where one has to again bit flip. Below is the code i've come up with the enable this to process successfully (so far). I've tested values from -10,000 to 999,999 and 0.0001 to 2.0002.

```
struct ValueExponent {
  int64_t value = 0;
  int32_t exponent = 0; // Powers of 10
};

int32_t CalculateExponent(const ::oracle::occi::Bytes& bytes, bool& isNegative) {
  int workingExponent = static_cast<int>(bytes.byteAt(0));
  isNegative = (workingExponent & 0x80) == 0;
  if (isNegative)
    workingExponent = ~workingExponent;
  bool isNegativeExponent = (workingExponent & 0x40) == 0;
  if (isNegativeExponent)
    workingExponent = ~workingExponent;
  return ((isNegativeExponent ? -1 : 1) * (workingExponent & 0x3f)) - (isNegativeExponent ? 1 : 0);
}

ValueExponent OracleNumberToValueExponent(const ::oracle::occi::Number& num) {
  auto bytes = num.toBytes();

  int64_t value = 0;
  bool isNegative = false;
  int32_t exponent = CalculateExponent(bytes, isNegative);

  decltype(bytes.length()) max = isNegative ? bytes.length() - 1 :  bytes.length();
  for(decltype(bytes.length()) ix = 1; ix < max; ++ix) {
    auto borig = bytes.byteAt(ix);
    int b = static_cast<int>(borig);

    b -= 1;
    if (isNegative)
      b = 100 - b;

    value = value * 100 + b;
     --exponent;
  }

  ValueExponent retval;
  retval.value    = isNegative ? -value : value;
  retval.exponent = exponent * 2; //Oracle exponents are of 100 not 10
  return retval;
}
```

This should be capable of outputting anything required I believe but anyone with advice on improving the algorithm would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know c++, so can't guess what you're expecting your output to look like for your code, but Oracle can convert numbers to strings including to scientific format, if that helps? e.g. `to_char(nbr, '0.99999EEEE')`

Comment: Thanks for your help with to_char but I'm hoping to get it into value exponent form to be compatible with the rest of my code which works that way for my floating point numbers and i'd rather avoid convert to string first to save a bit of processing power as it can be doing many thousands of these a second.

Comment: What is the output you're expecting? E.g. if the original number is -10,000, what is the output you're expecting?

Comment: using -10,000 as example i'm expecting any of:
    value: -1 exponent: 4;
    value: -10 exponent: 3;
    value: -100 exponent: 2;
    value: -1000 exponent: 1;
    value: -10000 exponent: 0;
if it were say -0.1 i'd expect something like:
    value: -1 exponent: -1

Comment: And your numbers are being retrieved from the database?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your numbers are coming from the database, you can apply the logic on the string, rather than reinventing how to derive the value and exponents, e.g.:

```
WITH nums AS (SELECT -10000 nbr from dual UNION ALL
              SELECT -0.99 nbr FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 0 nbr FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 0.0001 nbr FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 0.99 nbr FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 2.0002 nbr FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 999999 nbr FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 1e23 nbr FROM dual)
SELECT nbr,
       sci_num,
       TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(sci_num, 1, INSTR(sci_num, 'E', 1, 1) - 1)) val,
       TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(sci_num, INSTR(sci_num, 'E', 1, 1) + 1)) EXP
FROM   (SELECT nbr,
               to_char(nbr, 'fm0D099999999999999999EEEE') sci_num
        FROM   nums);

       NBR SCI_NUM                           VAL        EXP
---------- -------------------------- ---------- ----------
    -10000 -1.0E+04                           -1          4
     -0.99 -9.9E-01                         -9.9         -1
         0 0.0E+00                             0          0
    0.0001 1.0E-04                             1         -4
      0.99 9.9E-01                           9.9         -1
    2.0002 2.0002E+00                     2.0002          0
    999999 9.99999E+05                   9.99999          5
      1E23 1.0E+23                             1         23
```

(the `nums` subquery is just a way to generate some test data to use in the query.)

If you need to implement this logic in PL/SQL instead, you can do something like:

```
DECLARE
  v_num NUMBER := -10001;
  v_val NUMBER;
  v_exp NUMBER;
  v_sci_fmt_num VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  v_sci_fmt_num := to_char(v_num, 'fm0D099999999999999999EEEE');
  v_val := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(v_sci_fmt_num, 1, INSTR(v_sci_fmt_num, 'E', 1, 1) - 1));
  v_exp := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(v_sci_fmt_num, INSTR(v_sci_fmt_num, 'E', 1, 1) + 1));

  -- dummy output
  dbms_output.put_line('number: '||v_num||'; value = '||v_val||', exponent = '||v_exp);
END;
/

number: -10001; value = -1.0001, exponent = 4
```

Comment: thanks; that's awesome resolution however i'm not in control of the SQL (it's cross-database) and so i'm just aware that the database has sent me back an oracle number and i now need to send it back as an internally represented amount, food for thought though whether i can make this work somehow

Comment: Is there not a built in c++ function (or some library or something) that would convert a number into scientific format, even if that number originated in Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Look at Oracle's own ODPI-C project code [dpiDataBuffer__fromOracleNumberAsText()](https://github.com/oracle/odpi/blob/477cf384e06090f7c54b696a40083db4452eec30/src/dpiData.c#L144-L145).